# How to run bash script within VS Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I want to run bash script when I hit `F5` and see the results in the terminal like I can do with python scripts or whatever. I tried to do that with `Bash Debug` however it automatically goes to the debug mode and stops at the first step even if I do not put breakpoint. This is the launch configuration I use.

```json
        {
            "type": "bashdb",
            "request": "launch",
            "name": "Run mysql test",
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
            "program": "/srv/gpf/dba/mysqlslap/run.sh",
            "args": []
        }
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I don't know about running `bash` in a **debug mode** (doesn't seem like you need those features based on your example) but you can easily get your script to run as a *Task* or *Build* option.

Place this at `.vscode/tasks.json` of your project dir

```json
{
    // See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=733558
    // for the documentation about the tasks.json format
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "label": "Run as Bash Script",
            "type": "shell",
            "command": "/bin/bash ${file}",
            "problemMatcher": [],
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

You can place whatever you want in the `"command"` parameter.

As you can see, it's of type `"kind": "build"` so I can hit <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> and this will execute in a terminal.

Note, you can also use the command palette (<kbd>F1</kbd> or <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>) and use `Task: Run as Task` too.

Source: https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/editor/tasks

Comment: running in debug means when you run the script and go step by step, set the breakpoints, watch runtime variable values and so on.

Comment: @DmitrijKultasev I re-read my answer and I meant no offense! I just mean "it didn't look like you needed breakpoints and the testing features". I will rephrase my answer there